# Is a compromised SQL Server sa account without a domain login enough to access database?

Tags: sql-server, security, database-administration

If a SQL Server account with system administrator rights is compromised but there is no access to a domain account, port 1433 is not exposed externally and SQL injection is not possible, is a compromise from outside the domain of the SQL Server database possible?

Comment: Are you asking whether a database can be compromised when someone knows a sysadmin login password but cannot physically connect to the SQL Server instance?

Comment: @DanGuzman - That is correct.

Comment: Without connectivity to the SQL instance, regardless of port or protocol, it will not be possible to login with any credentials. This raises the question of how any application can connect.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman. Applications inside of the firewall have connectivity. I've updated the question to clarify. The question is whether there is any possibilty the sql account could be used if you were outside of the firewall and did not have domain account access.